# Only show menu item in debug mode?

Tags: android, debugging

In my app I have created a test page with some code that only will be available for the developer. This page/activity can only be reached via a menu-item. Is there a way to determine if an android app is running in debug mode, and only show the menu-item when this is true?

regards,
Goldhorn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check if the [debuggable="true"](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#debug) is set in AndroidManifest.xml. See this post for more info - [Getting "debuggable" value of androidManifest from code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276857/getting-debuggable-value-of-androidmanifest-from-code)

Answer (score 13):

To directly check debug mode in menu or another resource XML, we can define **resValue** in `build.gradle` like below.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        ...
        resValue "bool", "DEBUG", "false"
    }
    debug {
        ...
        resValue "bool", "DEBUG", "true"
    }
}
```

In `generated.xml` we will get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <!-- Automatically generated file. DO NOT MODIFY -->

    <!-- Values from build type: debug -->
    <bool name="DEBUG">true</bool>

</resources>
```

Now we can use this values and in `menu.xml`:

```
<item android:visible="@bool/DEBUG" ... />
```

Comment: And to get the value programatically:  `DEBUG_MODE = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.DEBUG);`

Answer (score -6):

USE THIS HACK

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String nOp = tm.getNetworkOperatorName();
if("Android".equals(nOp)) {
    // ADD YOUR MENUS FOR EMULATOR
}
else {
    // ADD YOUR MENUS FOR DEVICE
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is exactly what I'm looking for. I am debugging on both emulator and device. So I don't want to know if the app is running in an emulator or on a device. I want to know if the app is running in debug mode or in 'production' mode

Comment: oh sorry ... Try @Vino's answer?

Comment: @Vino's answer was what I was looking for :D