# Android - How to check if Developer option is enabled

Tags: android, developer-tools, android-developer-api

How can I check if the user has developer option enabled on its device?
(not with adb comunication active, or debug USB active, I need to know only if Developer Option are enabled).

I've tried this solution:
[How to check programmatically whether app is running in debug mode or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022653/how-to-check-programmatically-whether-app-is-running-in-debug-mode-or-not)
but it doesn't work for me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far

Comment: @AbhinavSinghMaurya see modified question

Comment: Device developer option enablement vs debug mode (the solution you referenced) are two separate things. Determining whether the developer option is enabled so the production app can kill itself for security, like Fortnight does, is something I do with my game app and would recommend to anyone who doesn't want their intellectual property hacked.

Answer (score 28):

try this:

```
int adb = Settings.Secure.getInt(this.getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Global.DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS_ENABLED , 0);
```

Comment: For API 16 You can use: `Settings.Secure.DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS_ENABLED`

Comment: For API lower than 16?

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is supported in API < 16. Other way is to work with try-catch block and open the preferences page if error occurred. `startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS));`

Comment: if it be 1 means that it is ebnabled or there is another value to check

Answer (score 4):

You should use
[getInt](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global.html#pubmethods) or another in Settings.Global
with 
 [DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS_ENABLED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global.html#DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS_ENABLED)

Edit : 
Below API 17, it is the same but with [Settings.Secure](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html)

Comment: But DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS_ENABLED was introduced in API 17. How can I check this on previous API level?

Comment: You will find it here below API 17 : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html

Answer (score 4):

Kotlin solution:

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
fun isDevMode(context: Context): Boolean {
    return when {
        Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN -> {
            Settings.Secure.getInt(context.contentResolver,
                Settings.Global.DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS_ENABLED, 0) != 0
        }
        Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN -> {
            @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
            Settings.Secure.getInt(context.contentResolver,
                Settings.Secure.DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS_ENABLED, 0) != 0
        }
        else -> false
    }
}
```

Comment: If using Kotlin, you can also make it a extension function

Comment: @IshaanKumar Of course, like probably every function. Are you asking me how to do it here?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a method that returns true if developer mode is enabled for all devices at Android 4.1 or above (API 16), returns false if developer mode is not enabled on such devices, and returns false on all earlier Android devices down to 1.0.

```
        @android.annotation.TargetApi(17) public boolean isDevMode() {
            if(Integer.valueOf(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK) == 16) {
                return android.provider.Settings.Secure.getInt(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),
                        android.provider.Settings.Secure.DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS_ENABLED , 0) != 0;
            } else if (Integer.valueOf(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK) >= 17) {
                return android.provider.Settings.Secure.getInt(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),
                        android.provider.Settings.Global.DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS_ENABLED , 0) != 0;
            } else return false;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
It's Simple to Find -- Developer Mode is On or Not!!!
Java solution:   

 if (PreferenceHelper.isDevMode(context)) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                builder.setMessage("Please Turn Off Developer Option \n" +
                        " \n" +
                        " Go to Settings > Search developer options and toggle them off.");
                builder.setCancelable(false);
                builder.setNegativeButton(" Ok ", (dialog, which) -> {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    finish();
                });
                builder.setPositiveButton(" Turn Off ", (dialog, which) -> {
                    startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS));
                });
                AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
                alertDialog.getButton(android.app.AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#37367C"));
                return;
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

I had search for so many methods finally i got the method and its is working fine in android studio also in app
it is mentioned below

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS));
```

Comment: This will open App settings page. How does this answer the question?