# Function to check development settings not working as expected

Tags: android

I have a function that checks if developer mode is enabled or not, as the suggestion here:

[Android - How to check if Developer option is enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31581830/android-how-to-check-if-developer-option-is-enabled#49602935)

Here is the code:

```
public boolean isDevMode() {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
        return android.provider.Settings.Global.getInt(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Global.DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS_ENABLED , 0) != 0;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

It works perfectly on API 26+ but I've just tested it on the emulator on API 24 and it returns false regardless of if developer settings are enabled or not.

What am I missing? Is it a different option for < 26?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by changing the default value to true for builds under oreo only.

```java
public boolean isDevMode() {
   if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        return Settings.Secure.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS_ENABLED, 0) != 0;
   } else {
        return Settings.Secure.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS_ENABLED, 1) != 0;
   }
}
```