# Flutter : How to Check Developer Mode Enable?

Tags: flutter, dart

I currently working to make application attendance prototype, in this application i [use google maps flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter). I want check if user enable developer option, because inside this have option to enable mock location. I want add more security to prevent user manipulate his location. If user detected actived developer mode , show dialog to turn off that.

Something Like this :

[image]

I have reference to make it with [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31581830/android-how-to-check-if-developer-option-is-enabled) , but i'm not familiar with native code .

How can i approach this ?

Thank's.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/jeroentrappers/flutter_jailbreak_detection

```
import 'package:flutter_jailbreak_detection/flutter_jailbreak_detection.dart';

bool jailbroken = await FlutterJailbreakDetection.jailbroken;
bool developerMode = await FlutterJailbreakDetection.developerMode; // android only.
```

thanks to appmire.be

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Use this plugin https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_jailbreak_detection

This will add a line like this to your package's pubspec.yaml (and run an implicit flutter pub get):

```
dependencies:
  flutter_jailbreak_detection: ^1.8.0
```

Import it
Now in your Dart code, and use it:

```
import 'package:flutter_jailbreak_detection/flutter_jailbreak_detection.dart';

bool jailbroken = await FlutterJailbreakDetection.jailbroken;
bool developerMode = await FlutterJailbreakDetection.developerMode; // android only
```