# How to check Android manifest parameters with code

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

I was wondering if it's possible to read a value from the Android manifest file programmatically. More specifically, I was wondering if the below pseudo-code is possible.

```
public void DebugLog(String label, String message) {
    // Display log messages only when debugging, i.e. not in the release product
    if (AndroidManifest.debuggable)
        Log.d(label, message);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how to check if the debuggable attribute is set in the manifest:

```
boolean isDebuggable = (0 != (getApplicationInfo().flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE));
```

Shamelessly stolen from here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4277868/483708