# Knowing if Android app is running from Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, android-activity

How can I know (in an Activity for example) that the app was installed and runned from Eclipse (plugged in mobile through USB)?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Maybe there is another solution to the root problem.

Comment: It is not a problem :) It would just help me develop. Because when I am developing I connect to test server and on production of course on production server. So I would just like to be a little more careful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All applications are signed by a certificate. Even when launched by eclipse.  When using the android SDK in eclipse, a debugging keystore was created by default and used each time you use the IDE to build and push your application to the device/emulator.

You can grab information about the keystore in your code and verify if it is your own signed code, or something else.  I used the quick and dirty code below on my application in eclipse:

```
    try {
        PackageInfo pi = this.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo( this.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        Signature[] signatures = pi.signatures;
        byte[] cert = signatures[0].toByteArray();
        InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(cert);
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509");
        X509Certificate cf509 = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(input);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Certificate issued by: " + cf509.getIssuerDN() );
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
```

The result was:

```
Certificate issued by: CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US
```

Better structured code and credit goes to this link:
http://thomascannon.net/misc/android_apk_certificate/

Answer (score 1):

Build your application from eclipse with [android:debuggable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#debug)=true flag. Then you can check its value from app with this approach: [Getting "debuggable" value of androidManifest from code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276857/getting-debuggable-value-of-androidmanifest-from-code)