# Android ant build changing global variable

Tags: android, ant

I have an ant build setup for my Android project, and I've been reading guides and tutorials all over stackoverflow and online, but cannot seem to understand how to make this work. Basically in my code I have a variable, "isDebugVersion" (which will print out logs, and a few other things). When I build with ant, I want that variable in my code to be set to "false". I'm looking around and I cannot find the `custom_rules.xml` examples even though it's listed in the `build.xml` file.

So the variable is in `com.example.application.Globals`, and it's listed as `isDebugVersion`. Can someone please give me an example for how to manipulate this variable using an ant build script?

Comment: While this isn't a direct answer to your question have you looked into using the debuggable flag in the Android manifest?  [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276857/getting-debuggable-value-of-androidmanifest-from-code) is a link to access the value in code.

Comment: I have, but part of the reason that I'm looking for this is because I'm also going to need to control variables like the "mapKey" used for the MapAPI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can a file named `custom_rules.xml` to the root folder of your project.
Inside define any property you want.

Note that what you are trying to achieve could be simpler using `BuildConfig.DEBUG`. This file is in the gen folder of your project, close to `R.java`. It is generated during the build and the constant `DEBUG` will be set to `false` during debug builds and to `true` in release.

So if you type `ant release`, you will get `false`. With eclipse or `ant debug`, you will get `true`.

You could also learn how to use RoboGuice, it has an [interesting logging solution](http://code.google.com/p/roboguice/wiki/Logging).

You can use this constant for all purposes like changing the google map api key from debug to release key. For an example, follow [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3029819/693752).

Comment: That's the debug flag in the AndroidManifest file though isn't it? I also need to be able to change variables like my mapKey for the Google Maps API

Comment: Can you update your answer with an example of how I would go about doing this?