# BuildConfig.DEBUG vs ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE

Tags: java, android, android-build, android-build-type, android-flavors

As refer by [Getting "debuggable" value of androidManifest from code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276857/getting-debuggable-value-of-androidmanifest-from-code), there are two options of checking if the build is debuggable:

1.) BuildConfig.DEBUG flag

```
 if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)`
```

2.) ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE

```
 if (0 != (getContext().getApplicationInfo().flags & 
     ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE))
```

Are they two identical, or they are different? When to use what?

Answer (score 12):

They are not identical.

There may be many `buildType`s, but `debug` and `release` are mandatory. `BuildConfig.DEBUG` will be `true` if currently selected build type is `debug`, otherwise it will be `false` (see exclusion case below).

`ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE` corresponds to following:

```
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }

        ...
    }
```

Now, `ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE` will be `true`.

Thus, you may conclude, that you may perform following:

```
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable false
        }

        ...
    }
```

Interestingly, although you are in `debug` build type, `BuildConfig.DEBUG` will become `false`.

Comment: What's the use of Debug where Debuggable is false?

Answer (score 5):

Found a good article here: http://tekeye.biz/2013/android-debug-vs-release-build.

Also tested it out. If we force `android:debuggable="false"` or `android:debuggable="true"` on Manifest Application, it will warn :

```
 Avoid hardcoding the debug mode; leaving it out allows debug and release builds to automatically assign one less...

 It's best to leave out the android:debuggable attribute from the manifest. If you do, then the tools will automatically insert android:debuggable=true when building an APK to debug on an emulator or device. And when you perform a release build, such as Exporting APK, it will automatically set it to false.  
 If on the other hand you specify a specific value in the manifest file, then the tools will always use it. This can lead to accidentally publishing your app with debug information.
```

I would conclude, in default situation `ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE` behave the same as `BuildConfig.DEBUG`, unless override by changing `android:debuggable`, which is not something advisable.

Compare to `BuildConfig.DEBUG`, `ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE` is a more reliable way to check for debug build, as at a lower dependent module, it can't access the `BuildConfig.DEBUG` of the parent module, and could have a different value.

e.g. App use MyLib module. App's `BuildConfig.DEBUG` could be false, but MyLib `BuildConfig.DEBUG` could be true. Hence it's better to check using `ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE`

Answer (score 2):

One area that did highlight the differences in the usages of these flags was following a pen test of our app. The pen test report pointed out to us that attackers can employ a technique called "hooking" where the app is recompiled with the android:debuggable flag changed to true (how this is done I'm not totally sure).

Their recommendation to detect this happening was to add some code as follows:

```
if (!BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        try {
            ApplicationInfo appInfo = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo("uk.co.myapp", 0);
            if ((appInfo.flags & appInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE) != 0) {
                // App has been compromised 
                finish();
                return;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

What you do when you detect this circumstance is down to you. I added it to my startup activity, and if triggered, I display a message followed by the finish() statement.

Answer (score 1):

My experience is that `BuildConfig.DEBUG` is always linked to the `debuggable` build attribute in the gradle file.

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
    debug {
        debuggable false
    }

    ...
}
```

The [documentation](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-BuildConfig) also supports this:

> - boolean DEBUG – if the build is debuggable.

`getContext().getApplicationInfo().flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE` was likely the only way to determine if a build was debuggable before the gradle build system and Android Studio replaced eclipse around 2015.

Use `BuildConfig.DEBUG` because it resolves to a constant which can be used during compilation to optimize code.