# What has the "android:debuggable" got to do with log printouts in DDMS?

Tags: android

my friends

I am testing some android apps, and I would very much like to know what has the "android:debuggable" got to do with log printouts in DDMS ??

Even if "android:debuggable" is set to false in the manifest, there also could be some Debug or Verbose logs printed in DDMS.

And when an app outputs lots of tedious logs, will it impact device performance in the long run?

And how would developers deal with this if they want to disable verbose and debug logs?

Thank you for commenting.

Regards.

Comment: Really appreciate if anybody would give a helping hand...

Answer (score 2):

So it seems that `Log` does not change depending on the setting of `android:debuggable`. I think it was meant to, but that has not been implemented.

There is a lot of discussion about the best way to implement this functionality. Generally this depends on placing a boolean before the log statement. I have copied a bit of this answer ([android.util.Log when publishing - what can I do / not do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4199921/383414)) below.

---

Good practice:

```
if (C.D) Log.d(C.T, "your log text here " + foo + bar);
```

Bad practice:

```
YourLog.d("your log text here " + foo + bar);

// and in YourLog.java's d() method:
... { if (debugging) Log.d(tag, text); }
```

---

Check the original answer for details please, since I just copied another person's answer.

---

In addition, for populating your boolean with the correct value automatically from the manifest, you can find code here: [Getting “debuggable” value of androidManifest from code?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4277868/383414)